# How to distinguish output panel from other activeTextEditor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

It is [known](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/58869) that `vscode.window.activeTextEditor` may return output panel.

Is there any way to determine the returned value is a real document or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex's solution will produce false positives, for instance for `.log` files or files where you manually switch the language mode to `Log`. I've been using the following in an extension, which seems safer:

```ts
activeEditor.document.uri.scheme == "output"
```